# Scroll form programmatically

Tags: c#

I have a form that I programmatically add panels, labels, checkboxes,and textboxes.  The form is larger than the screen size.  I am using screen capture to record the image of the text box to file for printing.  How do I programmically scroll down the form so I can capture the next image?

I have tried moving the cursor but that does not change what is displayed on the screen.  I have researched and found how to scroll in a panel but not a form.

Comment: Is this winforms or WebForms?

Answer (score 0):

In a Windows Forms application you can scroll a control into view with

```
 ScrollControlIntoView(pictureBox2);
```

You can so set a precise position with

```
VerticalScroll.Value = 200;
```